# "scrapy list" command in my project directory starts a spider

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I created a scrapy project form the command line and added two spiders, myspider1 and myspider2. Whenever I run "scrapy crawl myspider1" or ""scrapy crawl myspider2" it starts "myspider1".

When I run "scrapy list" it also starts myspider1

I am running this under a vertualenv in python but I can't understand why it does this. It seems that whenever I run a command with scrapy it always executes the first spider in my spiders folder.

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: can you share console logs of what you see? can you share your spiders code? what's your directory structure?

Comment: Exactly which command are you using for 'scrapy list' to run multiple spiders?

Answer (score 0):

The code was printing some print statements that made it delay the response which made me think it was crawling.